# Loop Using Javascript in chart / Echart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have this object and i need to convert to pie chart (i'am using echart apache)

```
var data = [
    {
        "Key": "Test1",
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "Key": "Test2",
        "value": 1
    }
]
```

and this my script to create a chart with real data but always show me the first value from data object (Test1 , 2) i don't now the problem :)

```
var chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
            var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
            var option;
            //console.log(UserSourceData);
            jQuery.each(UserSourceData, function (i, val) {
                    option = {
                        title: {
                            text: '某站点用户访问来源',
                            subtext: '纯属虚构',
                            left: 'center'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            trigger: 'item'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            orient: 'vertical',
                            left: 'left',
                        },

                        series: [
                            {
                                name: '访问来源',
                                type: 'pie',
                                radius: ['30%', '60%'],
                                data: [
                                    { value: val['value'] , name:  val['Key'] }
                                ],
                                emphasis: {
                                    itemStyle: {
                                        shadowBlur: 10,
                                        shadowOffsetX: 0,
                                        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                });

            option && myChart.setOption(option);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what UserSourceData represents but if you want the datapoints from the data object,you need to run the loop only for the data property within the options object.A [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function would do the trick.

```
var chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
const option = {
                        title: {
                            text: '某站点用户访问来源',
                            subtext: '纯属虚构',
                            left: 'center'
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            trigger: 'item'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            orient: 'vertical',
                            left: 'left',
                        },

                        series: [
                            {
                                name: '访问来源',
                                type: 'pie',
                                radius: ['30%', '60%'],
                                data: data.map(obj => ({value:obj['value'],name:obj['Key']})),
                                emphasis: {
                                    itemStyle: {
                                        shadowBlur: 10,
                                        shadowOffsetX: 0,
                                        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    };

 option && myChart.setOption(option)
```